# registerReceiver for Broadcast only if it's not already registered?

Tags: android

I have a snippet of code that I'm calling from a service:

```
context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            WifiManager mWm = (WifiManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            ret = mWm.isWifiEnabled();
            // DO MORE STUFF HERE
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));
```

What I would like is a way to check and make sure that the `registerReceiver` isn't already listening before it calls it again.  Is this possible?

For example if my snippet of code is in a method, and I call the method 10 times, right now the `onReceive` method appears to run 10 times.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There isn't a way of finding out — you should only be calling `registerReceiver` once, most likely upon the creation of your service.

You need to keep a reference to the `BroadcastReceiver` too for when you call `unregisterService` (`onDestroy()` is the natural place for it), otherwise the system will warn you about leaking broadcast receivers and get angry and possibly shout at you.

Comment: Looks like you are right, I needed to use a Thread in my service to keep it from firing off over and over.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this

```
class Thing {
    interface R {
        void onReceive(Context c, Intent i);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    private IntentFilter filter;
    private boolean isRegistered = false;

    public Thing(Thing.R r, String... actions) {
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                r.onReceive(context, intent);
            }
        };
        filter = new IntentFilter();
        for (String a : actions)
            filter.addAction(a);
    }

    public void register(Context c) {
        if (isRegistered) return;
        c.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        isRegistered = true;
    }

    public void unregister(Context c) {
        if (!isRegistered) return;
        c.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        isRegistered = false;
    }
}
```

then

```
Thing t = new Thing((c, i) -> {
    try {
        WifiManager mWm = (WifiManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        ret = mWm.isWifiEnabled();
        // DO MORE STUFF HERE
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}, WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
```

now call `t.register` as many as you like!